# How to extract specific parts of a large batch of strings?

Tags: notepad++

For example.

```
64d134a354eb2bf43626a73091514a2d:QMP0R\khOiPmkW1>bP,_-NTY4%-!P#:a123456
7d057d46b88f2cf4845dec57be4f3158:iR+LE[SQ\R~~o*+CCNL?i)mC>$G:U#:123321
6e0c116855a273f0c8c41dec1d21c160:s'?:fL2/mVj{&[`Onkyqf"y~47^YU#:abc123
```

All strings follow a three part pattern. The first two parts each separated by a colon and the required element following the second colon.

Exception: In part two of the string, there also exists the occasional colon. (see the third line ending in "abc123")

My proposal would be to reverse all of the strings and, once done, eliminate all characters after and including the first colon. When completed, reverse the text again to end up with the required elements, which should read:

```
a123456
123321
abc123
```

Note: This is to be applied to a large batch of such strings!

Answer (score 3):

In Notepad++, you can use its Find & Replace feature to remove everything before the third segment.

Simply use this find, with the Regular Expressions radio button on:

```
^.*:(?!.*:)
```

And replace by nothing, then hit Replace All.

[image]

What the expression means is:

```
^       Ensure match begins at the start of the line
.*      Match any number of characters
:       Until it matches a colon (:)
(?!     And ensure that after the colon, there are no...
  .*:   Colon after any number of characters on the same line
)
```

Result:

[image]

---

If the third part can contain colons as well, but it will always start with `#:` when compared to the other parts, then you can use a slightly different expression for the find:

```
^.*#:
```

And replace with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you can do this.

The easiest way is probably to just load your file in the Sublime text editor, and ctrl + middle click at the beginning of the first bit of text you want to keep (a123456) and drag the middle click down to the bottom right of the document. You should have all of your wanted text highlighted. Then ctrl + c, ctrl + v into a new file. This is assuming that all the lines have the desired text starting at the same location, which looks like column 67 from your example.

If not, load up the file in sublime, hit ctrl + f, and then click the `.*` button in the find toolbar at the bottom. Search for

`#:(.*)`

Click find all on the right, then copy and paste it into a new document. Ctrl + f to find again, search for

`^..`

find all again, and delete.  This leaves you with nothing but your strings at the end (a123456, 123321, abc123)

How does this work? The `.*` button search for Regular Expressions, or Regex. Regex defines rules by which you match patterns of text. Your rules are pretty simple here: Find the text starting with `#:` and grab everything after it. You could probably have done it in one step, but I'm not the greatest with Regex yet. so what we do is search for `#:`, followed by any number (`*`) of any character (`.`). We then copied this to a new file.

Then, we matched the beginning (`^`) two characters (`..`) and simply deleted them to be left over with the text we want.

I recommend you use Sublime text editor for this because it's free, fast, and it's search feature lets you very very easily selected disconnected groups of text and copy + paste them elsewhere. Notepad++ can do it too but it's regex feature adds a bunch of garbage text indicating where it found the matches, which of course you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is take all the strings and import them into excel or some other spreadsheet program.  use the Colon as the column separator and you should have all the elements in the 3rd column of the table.

Most of the data would be in the third column and some would be in the fourth, and presumably there could be instances of many colons in the data so I would insert a column at the start, that looks across the row and finds the last cell with data in it and puts that in the first column.

Something like this formula which i tested in Excel 2010:

=IF(ISBLANK(D1),C1,IF(ISBLANK(E1),D1,IF(ISBLANK(F1),E1,F1)))

will look through C, D and E rows and put the value from the last column in the cell with the equation.

This formula only looks at 3 columns, it could be modified infinitely

If you use fill down to fill the column you should get the answers you are looking for in col A.

Answer (score 0):

You a text editor with regex search and replace capabilities. Your search term should be:

```
.*:(.*)
```

The replace with should be:

```
\1
```

I used Sublime Text, but notepad2/Notepad++ will work.

Regex explanation:

```
.* - Matches any number of characters
:  - Match a colon
(.*) - Match any number of character as a subgroup
```

Then the `\1` replaces the entire matched line with the contents of the subgroup (the text you want). Regex is greedy by default (in most implementations) and will match the longest strings possible. That means this regex will match as many characters as possible before the second part of the regex (a colon followed by any number of characters).